# Ajax não entra no success

Tags: ajax

E estou tendo uma dificuldade em Ajax.

tenho o seguinte:

```
      beforeSend: function ()
      {
          $("#btnEvniar")
          .prop('disabled', true)
          .click(JaClicouProc(3,this));
      },
      success: function (resultado)
      {
          FechaDivAg();
          swal({
            title: "Sucesso!",
            text: "Helpdesk enviado com Sucesso.",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer:3000,
            html: true
          });

          $(".cam").each(function () {
              $(this).val('');
          });
      }
```

A função `JaClicouProc()` trava a tela para que o usuário não fique enviando vários *helpdesks*...

Porém não entra na parte de sucesso do Ajax. esta função `FehcaDivAg()` destrava a tela.

No arquivo alvo do Ajax que é um arquivo .php estou dando um `echo "true";`

Alguém sabe o porque não esta entrando em *success*?

Segue código da função conforme solicitado!

```
function JaClicouProc(qualmsg, wcam, msgopc)
{   
   if (typeof(msgopc) != "undefined")
       ShowAguarde(qualmsg, msgopc);
   else
       ShowAguarde(qualmsg);
//     ShowAguarde(qualmsg);    :MostraAguarde
   document.getElementById(wcam.id).blur();
// gab 2016-07-26. Usa a função para não processar duas vezes (a mesma do botão salvar)
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Se não entra no Sucess é porque está travando no beforeSend, ele funciona em cascata. Como você mesmo disse, a função JaClicou trava, o erro deve estar nela.

Comment: Coloca o Ajax completo porque outros parâmetros podem influir no resultado.

Comment: mesmo retornando true na função jaClicou? o ajax completo é bem grande! posta mesmo assim?

Comment: Tá entrando no beforeSend?

Comment: sim está entrando.

Comment: Faz um teste: comenta todo o beforeSend e veja se entra no success... se entrar, o problema é no beforeSend.

Comment: então tenta dá um ao invés de `echo "true"` tenta dar um `echo json_encode( array( 'retorno': true ))`

Comment: bom... comentei a função e deu certo... o código é da empresa em q estou trabalhando e não posso mexer em algumas funções... era a função JaClicouProc realmente... Obrigado!

Comment: Se puder colocar o que tem nessa função pra ver o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a função `beforeSend` não retornar `true`, a requisição é abortada, [conforme diz a documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Faça assim:

```
beforeSend: function ()
{
    $("#btnEvniar")
      .prop('disabled', true)
      .click(JaClicouProc(3,this));
    return true;
},
```

Comment: Legal amigo... agora funcionou perfeitamente... Obrigado! infelizmente fui vetado para fazer mais perguntas... Obrigado a todos.